# Path to be added in form:select spring mvc portlet

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

My project is a portlet with spring mvc. I would like to improvize my code, so I am trying to use `<form:select>` instead of `<select>`. I would like to know what changes are required for using it. The selected value should be returned to the controller.

jsp:

```
<form:form  modelAttribute="drpdownValue" method="get" action="${URL_EOBLIST}">
<form:select path ="values">
<form:options items="${dropValues}"/>
</form:select>
</form:form>
```

Model class:

```
public class DropDownValues {
String values;

public String getValues() {
return values;
}

public void setValues(String values) {
this.values = values;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping
public String initialize(RenderRequest renderRequest){      
ModelMap modelMap=new ModelMap();
modelMap.addAttribute("drpdownValue",new DropDownValues());    
return "formTable";//jsp name
}
@ModelAttribute("dropValues")
public List<String> getList(){
List<String> dropdown=new ArrayList<String>();
dropdown.add( "All Available");
dropdown.add( "Last 18 Months");
dropdown.add( "Last 12 Month");
dropdown.add( "Last 6 Months");
dropdown.add( "Last 3 Months");
return dropdown;
}
```

Comment: Using `<form:select>` instead of what?  What do you mean by "improvize my code"?  A `<form:select>` works no different than any other form input, except you can specify options because it's a select.  All that is required is that you set the path to some property in your model attribute for the form and have the values of the options be a meaningful and convertible value.

Comment: form:select instead of select. The application is working fine. But the ADD states to use <form:select>. I did the same as you mentioned. But I am getting this error "ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'drpdownValue' available as request attribute"

Comment: posting the code in my question. Am i missing anything here? @CodeChimp

Comment: The error is saying that your `modelAttribute` on the form is not there.  The issue is in how you have your handler method coded.  I do not believe you can simply create a `Model` in the middle and things work.  Pass it in as an argument to the handler, and Spring should provide you one.

Comment: Passing to handler, does that mean to the controller? I am doing that in initialize method. modelMap.addAttribute("drpdownValue",new DropDownValues());    Is there any other palce i need to add?

Comment: You should not be creating a ModelMap.  You should include it as an argument to your handler method (the method in your controller that is handling your request) and let Spring build it for you.  Please refer to section 19.9.4 of the Spring Framework Reference Guide:  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#portlet-ann-requestmapping-arguments

Comment: done this way... Still not working.....           public String initialize(RenderRequest renderRequest,ModelMap modelMap){
   modelMap.addAttribute("drpdownvalue",new DropDownValues());  s

Comment: Is there an error in the JSP, or it's just not displaying the options?

Comment: Its error in jsp. It is not even hitting the controller. I modified the code to return the model object directly with @ModelAttribute annotation, which resolved that error. Hitting with another error now

Comment: Please update the code above and specify the error you are getting.